# Dynamic position of progress bars based on results for multiple sections

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a rather interesting question here that I've been stumped on for awhile. We're playing with dynamic results that we'd like to indicate on reports.

We'd like to display a "marker" (*darker section*) where the end users result ends up in. These are Pathology Results and an example would look like the following:

[image: showing result..]

For the above example, the details are as follows:

- **RESULT**: 128
- **LOW RANGE:** 115
- **HIGH RANGE:** 165

As you can see above in the example graph there are 3 sections:

- Yellow (**LOW**): indicates a result that is below normal/outside of the lower range.
- Green (**GOOD**): to indicate a result that is good and within optimal ranges.
- Red (**HIGH**): indicates a result that is above normal/outside of the upper range.

Another example of what we're trying to achieve would look like the following - however this is all done statically at current:
[image]

**Notes**

- We already now which "section" it'll be in, but we need to create functionality to indicate "where" in that section it would end up, preferably percentage based.

For the **Low** range we've come up with a simple (*pseudo*) solution as follows:

```
$result = 1.15;
$rangeLow = 2.0;

function getLowRangePercentile($result, $rangeLow) {
    // number format as we only want the percentile, i.e. 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, etc...
    // NOT: 0.45, 0.98, etc...
    return number_format($result / $rangeLow, 1);
}
```

For the **High** range we've used a similar solution:

```
$result = 364;
$rangeHigh = 360;

function getHighRangePercentile($result, $rangeHigh) {
    return number_format($rangeHigh / $result, 2);
}
```

<sup>There are inherent issues with this as some results and/or ranges could have larger numbers causing the percentiles to be highly specific, i.e. `99%` in the above example...</sup>

---

We need to be able to generate HTML (Bootstrap) progress bar's as follows, with the "indicator" being 2% bar of the darker colour for the section it ends up in..

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-light-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 23%" aria-valuenow="23" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <!-- START "INDICATOR" marker -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 2%" aria-valuenow="2" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
     <!-- END "INDICATOR" marker -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-light-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-light-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

## NOTE

The sections are divided up as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------
|   LOW   |      NORMAL      |   HIGH   |
-----------------------------------------
|   25%   |        50%       |    25%   |
-----------------------------------------
```

Would love some ideas in terms of sorting this out efficiently for the low/high sections, along with the "good/normal" section (*as below*).

Which leaves us stumped on how to work on the "good" result section currently. We've currently thought of doing the following:

- Finding out which "range" the result is closer to
- Running a similar calculation to the other sections specified by the ranges
- Generating the progress bars from there...

Thanks.

Comment: do I misunderstand or does your question have conflict?  your 2 examples have definite ranges but you also mention 25%-50%-25%. these conflict I think. ranges are understandable but what 25% means for example for your 1st example (115-165)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing lol, but I'd try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/RazerMoon/wzhexb08/).

Assuming you want a consistent scale e.g. 0-25% is NOT equal to 0-115, I'd do the following:

1. Don't mess around with trying to balance four progress bars, just use three for the ranges and use an `absolute` positioned div as the marker.
2. Do some *maths*, let's use your first example (`res`: 128, `min`: 115, `max`: 165):

   1. Since `max` - `min` = 50% of the bar, divide that by 50 to get 1%

      - 165 - 115 = 50, 50 / 50 = 1
   2. We need to get the lowest value that can fit on the graph so we can adjust the position of the result:

      - 115 - 1 * 25 = 90
   3. Now that we know the scaling and the smallest value that can fit on the bar, subtract our smallest value from `res`, and divide by the 1% to adjust for scaling:

      - 128 - 90 = 38, 38 / 1 = 38%

Then just use that as the position of the div e.g. using the `left` property.